# Python/OpenCV Tkinter Exceptions

Tags: windows, python-2.7, opencv, tkinter, pycharm

With respect,

i am new to python and i am developing a gui with python/opencv which displays two images. One original and other one processed(edges display). My program crashes with errors. Following is the code: 
`

```
from mtTkinter import *  
import tkFileDialog
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
import cv2

def select_image():
    global  panelA, panelB
    path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

    if len(path) > 0:
        image = cv2.imread(path)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 100)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        image = Image.fromarray(image)
        edges = Image.fromarray(edges)

        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        edges = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

        if panelA is None or panelB is None:
            panelA = Label(image=image)
            panelA.image = image
            panelA.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)


            panelB = Label(image=edges)
            panelB.image = edges
            panelB.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=10,pady=10)

        else:
            panelA.configure(image=image)
            panelB.configure(image=edges)
            panelA.image = image
            panelB.image = edges
root = Tk()
panelA = None
panelB = None


btn = Button(root, text="Select an image", command=select_image)
btn.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes", padx="10", pady="10")

root.mainloop()
```

`
Errors are:

```
   `C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/BlackHat/PycharmProjects/example/init.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/BlackHat/PycharmProjects/example/init.py", line 21, in select_image
    edges = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 108, in __init__
    mode = Image.getmodebase(mode)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 295, in getmodebase
    return ImageMode.getmode(mode).basemode
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageMode.py", line 52, in getmode
    return _modes[mode]
KeyError: <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x02DD05B0>
Exception in Tkinter callback
Exception AttributeError: "'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'" in <bound method PhotoImage.__del__ of <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x02DD0790>> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/BlackHat/PycharmProjects/example/init.py", line 21, in select_image
    edges = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 108, in __init__
    mode = Image.getmodebase(mode)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 295, in getmodebase
    return ImageMode.getmode(mode).basemode
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageMode.py", line 52, in getmode
    return _modes[mode]
KeyError: <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x02DD0890>
Exception AttributeError: "'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'" in <bound method PhotoImage.__del__ of <PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x02DD0850>> ignored

Process finished with exit code 1`
```

There were two or more queries like this on stackoverflow but i did not find proper solution to the problem.

Please help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

> Blockquote

```
    image = Image.fromarray(image)
    edges = Image.fromarray(edges)

    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
   >>edges = ImageTk.PhotoImage(**image**)<<
```

> Blockquote
>
> Blockquote

```
    edges = ImageTk.PhotoImage(edges)
```

> Blockquote

is what is should say. You are converting a PhotoImage to a PhotoImage here.